# Mobile Specific css not showing up on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I am testing on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus phone with a screen of 720px wide. This is what I was trying to use to call out using a mobile css sheet for mobile devices only:

```
<link href="mobile.css media="only screen and (max-device-width:780px) rel="stylesheet" />
```

As well as using:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

to scale the desktop version for tablets.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing a `"` after `"mobile.css`

Comment: `media="only screen and (max-device-width:780px)`  <--- missing closing quote also here

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the just use media queries in my main css file to accomplish the same thing. Could make your life easier.

Comment: My only problem with using that is, there are a few design differences between the mobile and desktop/tablet version. Therefore causing some serious css to go on - otherwise I would totally use the @media { }

Comment: I use this technique all the time, using one style sheet and a minimal amount of style sheets as possible. One way I try to simplify my process, is to make the parent wrapper a static width and all it's children fluid/responsive. Then when the layout hits a certain width, make the parent fluid as well (aka width:100%). When the parent resizes, all the children are already prepped to do the same. I think that approach saves some k size in the long run.